# Relation between $d_\infty$ and $d_p$

Tags: real-analysis

Hi I am trying to prove that $$d_\infty(\bar{x},\bar{y})=\lim_{p\to\infty} d_p(\bar{x},\bar{y})=\text{max}\{|x_i-y_i|\}$$ where $d_p(\bar{x},\bar{y})=\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-y_i|^p\Big)^\frac{1}{p}$

I am stuck at the following 
\begin{align*}
d_\infty(\bar{x},\bar{y})&=\lim_{p\to\infty} d_p(\bar{x},\bar{y})\\
&=\lim_{p\to\infty} \Big(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-y_i|^p\Big)^\frac{1}{p}
\end{align*}

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $a_i = |x_i-y_i|, a = \text{max}(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$, then you have: $a < d_p(\bar{x}, \bar{y})< n^{\frac{1}{p}}a$, and the answer follows from squeeze theorem.